# CSS Menu Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS menu as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/vZgTP/15/

In the menu there is an arrow mark as shown below:

[image]

I can select (highlight)  the child menu items only if drag the mouse just below the arrow mark. Moving the mouse down with other places does not allow highlighting the children (they just disappear).

[image]

I am trying to achieve two things:

1)  Allow the children selected irrespective of the arrow mark

2)  Remove the arrow mark [The arrow should not come in the picture at all (even if I don't hover).]

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/vZgTP/21/

**Remove the arrow mark:** just remove `#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before` completely

**Allow the children selected irrespective of the arrow mark**

Change `padding:6px 20px;` of `#cssmenu > ul > li > a`

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{ 
 outline:none; 
 display:block; 
 position:relative;
 padding:6px 20px; /*Change This*/
 font:bold 13px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 text-align:center; 
 text-decoration:none; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I modified it as http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/vZgTP/24/. How can we remove the black border which is on top of the child element (bottom of main menu) to have better visual appearance? I tired to add  "border-top: 2px solid #FF5500;"to remove the black border- but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

index properties as like this

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{
z-index:999;
}

#cssmenu ul li > ul, #cssmenu ul li > div{
z-index:99;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/vZgTP/17/

--- **updated**

now do this in css file

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{
display:none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover a:before{
display:block;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/vZgTP/19/

Comment: Both issues are still there even in the updated fiddle when I tested with Chrome  http://jsfiddle.net/vZgTP/17/

Comment: i think you say if i selected parent navi than arrow is remove of your navi

Comment: I will clarify.. The arrow should not come in the picture at all (even if I don't hover).

Comment: I made a change and now its working http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/vZgTP/20/. Do you notice a difference in the position of the children in IE7 and Chrome? Can we make it work like Chrome even in IE7?